# Problem with string translation& java code

Tags: java, android

I asked a freelancer to make an app for me, I am a beginner in java but I know the basics. so when I tried setting up the translation with string files. I see this code can't be translated.
I tried R.String.... but it doesn't work. 
Here is the code.

```
private void updateLabel() {
    int date_length = 272;
    date_length += spCycle.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String result = **"Based on a last menstrual period of "** + String.format("%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY", calendar) + **" and a "** + spCycle.getSelectedItem().toString() + " menstrual cycle :\n\n";
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date_length);
    result += **"Your baby's estimated due date is on or around "** + String.format("%1$tA, %1$tb %1$td, %1$tY", calendar) + "\n\n";
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 14 - date_length);
    result += **"Conception likely took place on "** + String.format("%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY", calendar) + ". \n\n";
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -14);
    int diff = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis()) / 3600000 / 24 + 1);
    result += diff + **" days have passed since the start of your pregnancy. There are "** + (date_length - diff) + **" days left until your due date."**;
```

Comment: What is it that you would like to translate? @Oussama Qarbach

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility
Are you correctly followed this article?

Comment: text between "   "

Comment: You might ascertain if your contract with the freelancer included the need to support localization. If so, have said developer change all of the Strings. Otherwise, you must find all of the Strings, put them into the correct file with the appropriate format (e.g., "Based on a last period of %s and a cycle of %s"), and then you will need to use a formatter with the appropriate retrieved String and format with the parameters. One hopes there is a modicum of such outputs that need to be changed.

Comment: just add those 4 strings into the string resources. this can be translated, just alike any other string. sorry for not intending to providing a more detailed answer, but when you say you paid for this level of code quality, then why should I provide better code quality free of charge?

Comment: @KevinO there isn't just `%s`, there also is `%d` for numeric values. it's all no problem, while the translations use the substitutions in the same order (which is not always the case).